# Adding multiple products and quantities to Prestashop’s Cart

Tags: javascript, html, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to add checkboxes so that customers can select which products they want, and add them to cart with a single click (provided that they are on the same page). Additionally, the popup will display the list of products that were added to the cart.

Here is the tutorial for Prestashop 1.6: http://nemops.com/prestashop-cart-multiple-products-quantities/#.XYm_-ZMza-w
but it does not work for Prestashop 1.7.

Comment: try to remove all `.unbind('click')` from the code of the example, Keep only `.click(function...`. also check broswer console for possible js errors. OR wrap your list into a form, [may this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53979360/add-product-to-basket-via-javascript-jquery-in-prestashop-1-7-5-0)

Comment: But this tutorial is working for Prestashop 1.6, not 1.7. I cannot find `ajax-cart.js` file in the new one, however, I've found `core.js`, but have no idea ho to change it

Comment: You don't have to change prestashop core files. the best practice to add features to your theme is to create a custom module [here the guide](http://doc.prestashop.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51184607). To add Product into the cart it's possible to send post/get request directly to prestashop cart controller the URL should be like  this `https://YOUR_SITE/index.php?controller=cart&add&id_product=10&qty=1&token=..........`

Comment: Your link contains the custom module tutorial for 1.6, not 1.7. I've found the proper one, but I still don't know how to start. Can you give some examples/tips?

Comment: here the guide for 1.7 modules development https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/, you can grab a 1.7 generic module skeleton here https://validator.prestashop.com/generator

Comment: The main question is how to send a POST request to Prestashop cart?

Comment: reed how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how to create a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example